# Penalty inserted by output routine

Tags: plain-tex, output-routine

I am using plain TeX (actually plain e-TeX) processed by a relatively recent version of MiKTeX (pdfTeX). 
Consider the following fragment of code that can be processed with plain TeX:

```
\noindent
A\par
\output={\unvbox255}
\break
\vskip 1pt
\noindent
B
\output={\showbox255 \plainoutput}
\end
```

According to my knowledge, I was expected that as the `\break` appears, the output routine re-inject the content of `\box255` inside the main vertical list, the `\vskip 1pt` be cleaned and a `\skip\topskip` inserted before the letter B. But this is not at all what happens: after the output routine has been first called as the break appears, a `\penalty10000` is (inexplicably) inserted into the main vertical list, and the `\vskip 1pt` is not cleaned but left in place (this is shown by the `\showbox` inside the definition of the second `\output` above). 
Is it a normal behavior of TeX or is it a bug?

Answer (score 6):

TeX only discards the skips if there are no boxes in the current page. The penalty of 10000 arises because of the following as described in the TeXBook:

> When the best page break is finally chosen, TeX removes everything
>   after the chosen breakpoint from the bottom of the  *current page,*
>   and puts it all back at the top of the *recent contributions.* The
>   chosen breakpoint itself is placed at the very top of the recent
>   contributions. If it is a penalty item, the value of the penalty is
>   recorded in `\outputpenalty` and the penalty in the contribution list
>   is changed to 10000; otherwise `\outputpenalty` is set to 10000.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I am trying to use a "transparent" output routine to track the footnotes inserted up to the current point, and I would like it be as transparent as possible. I know no other method but to put a \break to invoke the ouput routine. But then, this penalty appears in the main vertical list. Is there a mean to remove it (or at least to make it harmless, say, by introducing a void box before the break)?

Comment: @MikeTeX look at `\holdinginserts`